# Is it a good practice to use aliases?

Tags: alias, conventions

I have a colleague who likes to use aliases instead of writing scripts, but I don't want to do this.

First, you need to set the same alias on each computer. They behave differently on different computers, which can confuse others. Unless you make an environment initialization script to initialize the alias.

Second, you need to read the alias and know which script he uses, then you can know what the alias do, but if you use a script command, you can directly know what you run.

Aliases will save some time on keyboard typing, but I don’t really like using them. Is it a good practice to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple commands, aliases can be extremely useful:

```
$ alias -p
alias l.='ls -d .*'
alias ll='ls -lAh'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

I would prefer this over creating new scripts for each of these shortcuts and then forwarding the arguments from my script to `ls`.  That just seems too pedantic.

However, `alias`es are generally user-specific.  If I define an `alias` in my personal `~/.bashrc`, I do not (and should not) expect anyone else to define the same alias.  That means I should not deploy scripts which parse the output of `ll`.

If I do have a script which uses `ll` and I want to deploy it, I have three options:

1. Ask all users of the script to also define this alias
2. Rewrite `ll` as a script and deploy it along with this script

3. Expand the alias in my script to `ls -lAh`.

Clearly option 3 is the easiest. Option 1 is going to make your life hard as you will spend more time arguing than being production. Option 2 seems like it's more effort than it's worth.

> Aliases will save some time on keyboard typing, but I don’t really like using it. Does it is a good practice?

To answer your question directly:  As long as you are not forcing your aliases on others, do whatever you like.  If you are willing to memorize some non-standard commands to save some time typing on the keyboard, then go for it.  However, that's a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No

- They are less powerful than functions and scripts.
- They only take arguments that are appended.
- You can define them all in one place (same for functions).
- You can find out which ones are defined by typing `alias`

Good and bad practice, depends on how you use them.

Comment: The current Bourne Shell (bosh) includes a concept from the 1980s that supports parameterized aliases.